# Google Maps Api V2 draw circle around current position

Tags: android, google-maps

Im currently working with Google Maps API V2 on an android project, I need to be able to draw a circle around the users current position and display markers for points of interest within the radious around the users current position.

Im struggling to get the small marker that denotes the users current position so i can draw a circle around it.

This is my code so far.

```
//Set up map and display users current position.
    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.nearbyMapSearch);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    final GoogleMap map = (((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nearbyMapSearch)).getMap());
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    //zoom to users location
    GeoLocationHandler geoHandler = new GeoLocationHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    Log.i("Search Fragment", "" + geoHandler.getCurrentLatitude() + " , " + geoHandler.getCurrentLongitude());
    LatLng loc = new LatLng(geoHandler.getCurrentLatitude(), geoHandler.getCurrentLongitude());

    //Begin animating camera.
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
            new LatLng(loc.latitude, loc.longitude), 13));

    //Instantiate new Camera position
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(new LatLng(loc.latitude, loc.longitude))
            .zoom(3)
            .bearing(0)
            .tilt(0)
            .build();
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Circle circle = map.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
     .center(new LatLng(loc.latitude, loc.longitude))
     .radius(1000)
     .strokeColor(Color.RED)
     .fillColor(Color.BLUE));
```

More info https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle

You should subscribe to updates of user location and reset the circle center with

```
circle.setCenter(newLocation);
```

Comment: Clearly ive been staring at the screen to long to not realise it was that simple. Getting a Null pointer error when getting the location however, but i think that is a completely different error.

Comment: Yes, it is a different problem with your code. It is because you cannot use the map before it is ready. All the stuff related to map initialization you have to move to you method onMapReady.

Comment: So everything escept for the fragment stuff needs to go in OnMapReady()?

Comment: In your code, yes. The GoogleMap object is passed to you through onMapReady parameter. So is on onMapReady callback where you have your map object ready to use (enable user location, animate camera, etc)

Comment: Okay cheers for clearing that up for me this is the first time ive used the V2 Api.

Comment: Sorry ive ot accepted this answer till now its been a busy week your code worked cheers :)